# Addressing the elephant in the room, why the way of writing $\cong$ and $\equiv$ is flipped?

Tags: tex-general

I have been a user of latex for the lest 10 years, and I have always wondered why to write `$\equiv$` we use "equiv" if the symbol that appears is usually referred to as the congruence symbol, and to write `$\cong$` we use "cong" when the symbol that appears is that of an isomorphism which is, in my opinion, much more closer to an equivalence.

I am sure that there is a very good reason, but I have always wondered what is this reason. Does any one know?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ A \cong  b \equiv C$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Those are just macro names. You are always free to make your own names: `\newcommand\isomorph{\cong}`. Different symbols means different things in different fields.

Comment: As others wrote, they can be redefined to whatever your want. For me anything with the word `isomorph`  or even `morph` needs arrows!

Comment: Unicode calls the first (U+2245) `Approximately Equal To`. The symbol is often used for congruence of geometrical objects, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry). The second (2261) is called `Identical To` and a similar symbol U+2263 (≣) is `Strickly Equivalent To`.  So imho the default LaTeX names are fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see no elephant, and I assure you I looked very carefully.

In order to make TeX usable, symbols must get a name. The LaTeX names are based mostly on those given by Knuth. Some of them are “agnostic”, such as `\otimes` or `\vert`, others reflect common usages.

The `\cong` symbol is frequently used in elementary geometry to denote “congruence”, according to Hilbert's school. It is *also* used in higher algebra to denote isomorphism.

On the other hand, `\equiv` is frequently used to denote “complete identity” (not something I like, but you see `f\equiv g` to denote that the functions *f* and *g* are the same, that is, they take on the same value at every point of their domains, where my algebra background would dictate `f=g`). It is *also* used in connection with Gauss congruences over the integers.

Knuth made a decision, which we may not agree with. It's too late for complaining, anyway, because thousands of documents have used `\cong` for denoting isomorphism.

If you're not satisfied by the semantics, define your own aliases:

```
\NewCommandCopy{\isom}{\cong}
\NewCommandCopy{\ceq}{\equiv}
\RenewCommandCopy{\cong}{\equiv}
```

although I discourage from doing the last one, because you risk misunderstandings if you share your source with coauthors.

Answer (score 6):

Both seem to be possible. From [Wikipedia on Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Notation) in geometry (all emphasis below mine):

> A symbol commonly used for **congruence** is an equals symbol with a tilde above it, ≅, corresponding to the Unicode character 'approximately equal to' (U+2245). In the UK, the three-bar equal sign ≡ (U+2261) is sometimes used.

And [about ≡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Identity):

> **Identity**
> The triple bar symbol ≡ (U+2261, LaTeX \equiv) is often used to indicate an identity, a definition (which can also be represented by U+225D ≝ EQUAL TO BY DEFINITION or U+2254 ≔ COLON EQUALS), or a **congruence** relation in modular arithmetic.

And [further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar):

> The triple bar or tribar, ≡, is a symbol with multiple, context-dependent meanings indicating **equivalence** of two different things. Its main uses are in mathematics and logic.
> ...
> ≡ is used for the higher-level metalogical notion of logical **equivalence**, according to which two formulas are logically equivalent when all models give them the same value
> ...
> In number theory, it has been used beginning with Carl Friedrich Gauss (who first used it with this meaning in 1801) to mean modular **congruence**: a ≡ b ( mod N ) if N divides a − b

Anyway, if you don't like the names in LaTeX then you can change them, as mentioned in a comment. And it's off-topic for the site anyway :)